# Pick the value from a text box id to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Iam getting a value to the text box id using AJAX which is working fine.

```
<input type='text' id='selectuser_id' />
```

Javascript

```
$( "#customers" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    var countrycode = '<?php echo $agencyid; ?>';
                        $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost:8000/core/country/fetch_customers.php",
                                type: 'post',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                        search: request.term
                                },
                                success: function( data ) {
                                        response( data );
                                }
                        });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#customers').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                        $('#selectuser_id').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input
                        var customerid = $("#selectuser_id").val(); //equals $q6[$t2] exactly

                        return false;
                }
        });
```

Now how will i pick this value to my PHP

```
<?php echo $selectuser_id; ?>
```

I tried many ways but not getting the result. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: there's no ajax call in the code you posted

Comment: I have edited the question. Have put the ajax code.

Comment: what is the `$agencyid` variable?

Comment: try with $_POST['search']

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show us where you hold the data of the input field i will give you an example.

Javascript side (since you are also using jQuery) you can get the value of the input field by id like:

```
let myValue = $( "#selectuser_id" ).val();
```

Then inside your ajax call you can include your data just like you did for the search:

```
        data: {
            search: request.term,
            myValue: myValue
        }
```

In your `fetch_customers.php` file you should be able to access your post data like:

```
$_POST['myValue'];
```